# Rodenstock Sironar N Compatibility

Tags: lens, old-lenses, large-format

Is the Rodenstock Sironar N 240mm F5.6 MC compatible with LF 4X5 camera ? Should I have any concerns ?

Comment: See also this question: [What are the differences among the various Rodenstock Sironar lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99704)

Comment: Also, according to this [random web link](https://www.largeformatphotography.info/forum/showthread.php?54812-Rodenstock-Sironar-N-240mm-F5-6-MC), the lens has an image circle of 350 mm - quoted as being plenty to cover 8x10. (Disclaimer: I don't really know anything about large format photography - I'm just thinking in terms of the image circle.)

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have a lens board that will take the shutter and a bellows that will allow extension to your closes planned focusing distance, you're good to go. You're *very* unlikely to run into any problems with movements with that lens; it has enough coverage that you'd be tying your bellows in knots before you run onto issues.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this list](https://www.graflex.org/lenses/lens-spec.html) published by Graflex, there are two different Sironar N 240mm F5.6 lenses. They cast image circles of 337mm and 350mm, respectively.

The nominal negative size for 4x5 is 102x107mm with a diagonal of ≈148mm, so you won't have any issues with image circle size.

Just be sure your lens board can take a lens that large in diameter, as some 4X5 cameras, particularly "folding" cameras, can not handle a lens that large.